# AppScript - Sorry, unable to open the file at this time. Please check the address and try again

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, fetch-api

I have a web form that sends a post request to AppScript with fetch.
I am seeing an error:
Sorry, unable to open the file at this time.

Please check the address and try again.

This is weird for 2 reasons.

1. the fetch used to work totally fine. It stopped working after I cleaned up some old deployments that I didn't want to use anymore. (I did some bad practice and made a new deployment for every save haha)
2. it's sending me to a different link than my appscript web url. Is this expected? I made sure that the fetch url is the proper web url, but it still sends me elsewhere.

I noticed that this problem has happened for other people in other posts, but their solutions don't work for me.
I am getting sent to a link in this format:
https://script.google.com/macros/s//exec

Things I've tried:
-signing out of all of my accounts
-using an incognito tab
-made sure access is set to anyone and execute as Me

The expectation is that the post request would submit the user's form data to my AppScript, which would then store the data in Google Sheets

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. Unfortunately, from your question, I cannot correctly imagine your current scripts of Google Apps Script and Javascript and the settings of your Web Apps. In order to correctly understand your question, can you provide the detailed flow for correctly replicating your current situation? First, I would like to correctly understand your question. I would be grateful if you could forgive my poor English skill.

Comment: Yeah definitely. I am trying to create an rsvp web page. Users fill out that form, and when they submit it, javascript will send a fetch post request to appscript. Then appscript will send that data to google sheets. However right now, after the user submits their form, I run into that weird error.

Comment: it seems your new deployment made the problem, and yes if you select new deployment you will have a new URL. If you want to stick to the previous URL, Edit > select new deployment. For your case  please double check you are setting `set to everyone` and using the correct URL provided by this new deployment. I cannot see another reason why it won't work

Comment: That's what I tried. Access is set to anyone, and I made sure to use the new url. So I have no idea why it isn't working. I even tried creating a new appscript file and using that url instead, but that didn't work either